# android json object looping and creating one single list with this json object

Tags: java, android, json

```
{
    "My Income": {
        "catResponse": null,
        "sum": [
            {
                "name": "Salary",
                "budgetvalue": 0,
                "actualvalue": 6000,
                "catID": 1,
                "iconname": null,
                "iconcolor": null,
                "budgetHeadId": 0
            }
        ],
        "spendAmount": 0,
        "incomeAmount": null
    },
    "My Growth": {
        "catResponse": null,
        "sum": [
            {
                "name": "IRA",
                "budgetvalue": 0,
                "actualvalue": 300,
                "catID": 23,
                "iconname": null,
                "iconcolor": null,
                "budgetHeadId": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "Mutual Funds",
                "budgetvalue": 0,
                "actualvalue": 500,
                "catID": 26,
                "iconname": null,
                "iconcolor": null,
                "budgetHeadId": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "My Goals",
                "budgetvalue": 0,
                "actualvalue": 150,
                "catID": 28,
                "iconname": null,
                "iconcolor": null,
                "budgetHeadId": 0
            }
        ],
        "spendAmount": 950,
        "incomeAmount": null
    },
    "My Protection": {
        "catResponse": null,
        "sum": [],
        "spendAmount": 0,
        "incomeAmount": null
    },
    "My Spend": {
        "catResponse": null,
        "sum": [
            {
                "name": "Rent & Utilities",
                "budgetvalue": 0,
                "actualvalue": 855,
                "catID": 5,
                "iconname": null,
                "iconcolor": null,
                "budgetHeadId": 0
            }
        ],
        "spendAmount": 855,
        "incomeAmount": null
    },
    "My Borrowings": {
        "catResponse": null,
        "sum": [
            {
                "name": "Education Loan",
                "budgetvalue": 0,
                "actualvalue": 1200,
                "catID": 18,
                "iconname": null,
                "iconcolor": null,
                "budgetHeadId": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "Credit Card Payment",
                "budgetvalue": 0,
                "actualvalue": -1790,
                "catID": 20,
                "iconname": null,
                "iconcolor": null,
                "budgetHeadId": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "Auto Loan",
                "budgetvalue": 0,
                "actualvalue": 600,
                "catID": 13,
                "iconname": null,
                "iconcolor": null,
                "budgetHeadId": 0
            }
        ],
        "spendAmount": 3590,
        "incomeAmount": null
    }
}
```

my code is some thing like this
JSONObject jObject= new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response)).getJSONObject("My Income");

```
  Iterator<String> keys = jObject.keys();
  Log.i("ky1",keys.toString());
  String keyname = null;
  String keyValue = null;
  while( keys.hasNext() )
  {
    if(jObject.isNull("catResponse") || response.isNull("incomeAmount")||response.isNull("iconname" )||response.isNull("iconcolor")) {
      try {
        jObject.put("catResponse", "0");
        jObject.put("incomeAmount","0");
        jObject.put("iconname", "0");
        jObject.put("iconcolor", "0");
        String  res  = jObject.toString();
        Log.i("newrespone1", res);
      } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

    }
    Log.i("kyname", String.valueOf(keys));
     keyname = keys.next();
     keyValue = jObject.getString(keyname);
    Log.v("keyValue", keyValue);
    Log.v("category key", keyname);
    JSONObject innerJObject = jObject.getJSONObject(keyname);
    JSONObject jo = jObject.getJSONObject(keyname);
    Iterator<String> innerKeys = jo.keys();
    while( innerKeys.hasNext() )
    {
      String innerKkey = innerKeys.next();
      String value = jo.getString(innerKkey);
      Log.v("key = "+keyname, "value = "+value);
      JSONObject totalObj = new JSONObject(value);
      if(totalObj != null){
        ModelHeader modelHeader = new ModelHeader();
        modelHeader.setIncomeAmount(innerJObject.getString("My Income"));
        modelHeader.setCatResponse(totalObj.getString("catResponse"));
        modelHeader.setSum(totalObj.getString("sum"));
        modelHeader.setSpendAmount(totalObj.getString("spendAmount"));
        modelHeader.setIncomeAmount(totalObj.getString("incomeAmount"));
        modelHeader.setMyGrowth(innerJObject.getString("My Growth"));
        modelHeader.setMyProt(innerJObject.getString("My Protection"));
        modelHeader.setMyBorrow(innerJObject.getString("My Borrowings"));
        modelHeader.setMySpend(innerJObject.getString("My Spend"));
        modelHeaderslist.add(modelHeader);
        JSONArray list = totalObj.getJSONArray("sum");
        if(list != null){
          for(int i = 0; i < list.length();i++){
            JSONObject elem = list.getJSONObject(i);
            if(elem != null){
              ModelBudget modelBudget = new ModelBudget();
              modelBudget.setName(elem.getString("name"));
              modelBudget.setBudgetHeadId(elem.getString("budgetHeadId"));
              modelBudget.setActualvalue(elem.getString("actualvalue"));
              modelBudget.setCatID(elem.getString("catID"));
              modelBudget.setIconname(elem.getString("iconname"));
              modelBudget.setIconcolor(elem.getString("iconcolor"));
              modelBudget.setBudgetvalue(elem.getString("budgetvalue"));

              budgetList = new ArrayList<>();
              budgetList.add(modelBudget);
```

here null point exception is coming ,so i replace every null of json object as zero,please help me how to deal with this json object..
how to deal with null point exception while iterration??

Comment: here is my entire json object,i want to itterate  this json object  and put into one single list..each json object header should be displayed on header of listview and rest all should be placed into listview rows..

Comment: i am new to this field...please help me out guys

Comment: check that link above it will help you **`BTW`** you what did you tried so far any efforts from your side first you need to put some efforts than if you face any problem than ask question here

Comment: i am posting my json iterration find this ..i am not able to iterrate it properly

Comment: Hi Nilesh,i posted my code just now check and say how to correct that